# Is it possible to generate HTML/JSP page automatically by JavaScript or jQuery or any other programming language like Java, PHP, ASP.Net etc?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, using, dynamically-generated

In my project, I want to create new HTML or JSP page dynamically using code. Is it possible by using any scripting or programming language?

Like - Google form, where form page is generated by coding.